# Android elements have white background behind the text on pre-lollipop and lower api versions

Tags: android, background, transparency, android-support-library, android-4.4-kitkat

I use `TabLayout` for `ViewPager`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector" />
```

but here's the result

[elements with white background at kitkat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L27jd.png)

`tab_color_selector` has 2 items with `state_selected="true"` and default. I also tried using tags like theese, but with no success:

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
app:tabBackground="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
```

Project includes all neccessary dependencies afaik

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

also tried

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Works perfectly at lollipop and newer api's. 
[elements displays great at api 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftLI0.png)

as you can see, tere is also png image in toolbar's menu that also doesn't have transparent background. I add imade like that

```
toolbar.getMenu().getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);
```

xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorMain"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

I really need help. If you have any ideas why background isn't transparent, please, let me know. Thank you

**UPD:**

I found that my base application theme has background tags (I accidentally recently added them and completely forgot about it). Removing them solved the issue.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

However, it is strange that they worked only on pre-lollipop api.

I suppose Mahesh's answer would also work. So I learned a lesson: check your styles, if something is not displayed correctly:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom style like

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        />
```

and in your style file

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I solved the issue, see comments in UPD section. I think your solution would also work

Comment: I'd like to do it, but I have less than 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

Make **tab_background.xml** in drawable folder and set
 **app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"** to your tablayour like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" 
      android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ....
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
    ...
/>
```