# How to change text label background color inside TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

For some reason cant change the text background color to transparent (replace white)
inside a `TabLayout`:

[image]

My `TabLayout`:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/reviewsFeedTabs"
        app:tabBackground="@color/mainBackgroundTheme"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/lightMainTheme"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/NavigationBarText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and my style:

```
<style name="NavigationBarText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:background">@color/testGreen</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/testGreen</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

`background` does not respond to `@color/transparent` either

Answer (score 0):

Use custom style like

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"

    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
    />
```

and in your style file

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
<item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
<item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
```

Answer by [Mahesh Gawhane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45254399/4894333)

Comment: Hammad Akram that did not change the white background around the text labels

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
 app:tabBackground ="#80000000"
```

Comment: actually thats not compiling